# Is this issue due to bots?

Tags: model-view-controller, bots

In our MVC website log I can see lot of errors with message "A public action method was not found". Requests are coming with junk action method name.
For example if I have action name "GetProducts" then requests are coming with actiona name as "GetProducts AND 1=1" , "GetProducts;id'" , "GetProductswhscheck".

is this because of internet bots are trying to access my website with junk values?

Comment: The first one smells like an attempt at SQL injection. Make sure your queries are parameterized!

Comment: Yes, your site is being scanned for vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be bots, it may be script kiddies, or it may be crackers. Either way - somebody is trying to find vulnerabilities on your site.

Let's look at the first one:

```
GetProducts AND 1=1"
```

This looks like an attempt at [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). There was probably a longer query after the "1=1", trying to get information out of your database - like usernames, e-mail addresses, and so on.

To defend yourself, make sure your queries are parameterized. You may also want to add some form of rate-limiting on your system; if possible, see if you can add captchas.

You may also want to look at [this answer on Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31231/5405), and the [OWASP top 10 security vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project).

Do this as soon as possible, because somebody's trying to break in to your system.